# Why there is no output when I do R Pattern Matching with For loop

Tags: r, for-loop, pattern-matching

This is the first time I wrote a R function. What I want to do is for example I have a R `data.frame` like this

```
                             Vars        match
1                             A_m          0
2                             B_m          0
3                               C          0
4                               D          34
5                               E_m        0
```

This is the result I got after matching two dataframes. In the `match` column, if the number is 0, it means there is no match for the value in the `Vars` column. For example in first row, A_m has 0 in match column. This means A_m doesn't have a match. So my function is to find those values in Vars column that has no match (has 0 in match column). After that if the value I found ends with "_m" then it is the value I want, and I want to print them out.

This is the code I wrote. Because I have never written R function before, there can be lots of problems with my code. I want to use `data.frame` as my function's argument and use `for` loop to check the whole dataframe. In the for loop I want to use if to decide whether it is the target value or not. Really appreciate for your help and Patience.

```
varsConvert <- function(x){
  for(i in 1:nrow(x)){
    #x[i,1]is the cordinate of the value in that dataframe, can I write like this?
    if(x[i,1] == 0){
      #I want to match ends with _m by *_m
      if(x[i,0] == "*_m"){
        print(x[i,0])
      }
      else if(x[i,0] == "E"){
          print(x[i,0])
        }
      else{
        stop("this is an error")
      }

    }
  }
}
```

In my example the values I want to print should be A_m, B_m and E_m

Comment: The pattern argument is the problem. The `*` is not a wildcard when used with `==`. You need to learn to use R regex functions. (Although I suppose you could use `substr()` with appropriate calculations with `nchar()` to set the lengths.

Comment: Thanks for your help! So is that the only problem with my code? If I use correct R regular expression my code can work?

Comment: I haven't tried testing whether the rest of the code is valid. I was just trying to answer your title-question about why yours was failing. I basically agree with ettenne that using for-loops is a bad idea.

Comment: Thanks! Really appreciate your help! I'm very new to this language

Comment: @user5601679: I have to add that in R the index start at 1 and not 0, which might explain why your code doesn't run.

Comment: Thanks! Your function works perfect for me. Really appreciate your help!

Comment: @etienne Can I ask a little more? In your function we can get A_m, B_m and E_m. So actually, those "_m" are useless part, and I only want the A, B and E. Is there a way to get the A, B, and E parts?

Comment: @etienne Should I ask a new question?

Comment: @user5601679: Try to replace the last line of the `f` function by `gsub('_m','',temp[grep('_m',temp)])`

Comment: @etienne Can I do 'data<-gsub('_m','',temp[grep('_m',temp)])' to put the result into a new dataframe?

Comment: @user5601679: If it's made in the function then it won't "exist" after the function. You can do `missingValues<-f(df)` and missingValue will be a vector with 3 values (A, B and E)

Comment: @etienne That's so helpful! Thanks Apologize for keep bothering you : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it is possible to write "classic" `for` loops in R, it's often best to use other functions which will be shorter/cleaner/faster. Here is your data (I named it `df`) :

```
df<-structure(list(Vars = c("A_m", "B_m", "C", "D", "E_m"), match = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 34L, 0L)), .Names = c("Vars", "match"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

You can do :

```
temp<-df$Vars[df$match==0] # find the names of Vars for which match is equal to 0
temp[grep('_m',temp)] # only select those with _m
# [1] "A_m" "B_m" "E_m"
```

An other option is to select the indexes of the intersection of match==0 and _m in Vars :

```
df$Vars[intersect(grep('_m',df$Vars),which(df$match==0))]
# [1] "A_m" "B_m" "E_m"
```

And yet another approach (using Boolean arithmetic rather than set operations):

```
df$Vars[ grepl('_m',df$Vars) & df$match==0 ]
```

If you want a function with a `data.frame` in input you can do this (I used column numbers this time to show other possibilities) :

```
f<-function(data){
    temp<-data[,1][data[,2]==0]
    temp[grep('_m',temp)]
}
```

To use it, call `f(nameOfYourData)` :

```
f(df)
# [1] "A_m" "B_m" "E_m"
```

Comment: I thought the set-operation approach was rather elegant, and hope the Boolean amendment is seen as "friendly".

Comment: @42- : yes thank you for the edit ! In addition using the boolean is faster than `intersect`

Comment: Thanks for your response, do you mean I only need those two commands or do I need to replace my for loop with those tow command lines?

Comment: @user5601679: just use the commands, you don't need the loops. The three options work "on their own"

Comment: Thanks, it works for me. But allow me to ask more questions. Because what I want to do is part of a main R code. So instead of commands I want to write a R function to do this. Can I modify my code and make it work?

Comment: @user5601679: You're welcome, I edited my answer by adding a function.  Please tell me if you need more explanations.

Comment: Thanks! So does it mean for loop is not very common to use in R? Because it's not very efficient? I saw what you do in your command, it seems when you choose a column and do match, it is actually doing loop it self. Am I understanding right?

Comment: @user5601679: `for` loops can be used but are generally replaced by other functions (the `apply` family for example). In R, you reason with vectors and a lot of functions take vectors as input. In the `match` function it will indeed "loop" over each element of the specified column to find if the value is equal to 0. And match is much faster than a for loop which will iterate over each row.